70's or 80's Animated film about Animals trying to survive their forest being torn down by humans for resources? (Not fanciful more realistic)
I remember a movie about a group of forest animals that were forced out of their homes in a forest because it was getting torn down by humans. So they went on an adventure to find another forest that wasn't being harvested. I remember two of the characters were hedgehogs (or a similar rodent like animal) and they were a husband and wife but at one point in the movie the animals have to cross a street with cars driving fast on it and one of the rodents freezes up and gets killed. Does anybody know what movie this is?

Found out the answer! Thanks for the help! https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090810183650AA5WXsa

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0VaAES0J20

Sounds like The Animals of Farthing Wood (1993-95), although that was a TV series and not a movie.  The TV show was based on a book of the same name, as well as 7 subsequent books written by the same author.

The books tell the story of a group of woodland animals whose home has
  been paved over by developers. They learn of a nature reserve, White
  Deer Park, where they will be safe, and undertake to make the journey
  together. They form an Oath, promising to protect one another and
  overcome their natural instincts until they reach their destination.

Here's a clip of the beginning of the series:




Is it Once Upon a forest ?? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107745/
Its similar but the road is in the forest itself.

No thats not it. The animals had less personification. As in they didn't walk on two legs ever, but they had enough human attributes to understand they were in danger and needed to relocate

found it thanks https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0VaAES0J20
